# Passing argument from app onlaunched to mvvmcross

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross, windows-store

From my Window Store app, I want to use the launch arguments coming from a toast into the app.xaml `OnLaunched` method. This launch argument might be a small JSON string or an ID to a model, I haven't decided. Now how do I pass it to mvvmcross for use from my view models?

Do I register it into the Ioc? Or can I use the optional parameter from the `IMvxAppStart.Start` method

```
      var start = Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.Resolve<Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxAppStart>();
      start.Start(e.Arguments);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can use either of the mechanisms you suggest - it's just C# code and it's free for you to use.

There's some notes on how to use AppStart for this purpose in https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/appstart-in-mvvmcross